# Strange runtime problems while compiling mono for 64 bit on Windows

Tags: windows, mono, 64-bit, mscorlib

I have an application uses Mono framework 2.10.2 with c# and works fine. Now i am trying to build it for Windows 64 bit.

I compiled all my projects and mono for 64 bit, linked and copied necessary binaries and libraries. My application is able to be compiled, linked and launched succesfully with 64 bit mono files.

But when I try to do some file operations, e.g. opening a file, it gives an access denied error. Same code  and same file works nice in 32 bit version. Or when i call some of my debug functions like opening a message box, it works just like I didn't call that function.

I checked current working directory with Directory.GetWorkingDirectory call. It returns a garbage value. I think this is why it can't find or access the file. Also I am trying to set working directory's value to somethings like E:\Develop but this time it says path not found.

Getworkingdirectory function is implemented in Microsoft's mscorlib.dll by default but Mono framework seems to use its customized mscorlib.dll. Do i have to find 64 bit version of this dll or am i missing something else ? I am building mono with mono's msvc folder which includes an visual studio solution.

Comment: What "garbage value" is returned by Mono's `GetWorkingDirectory()`?

Comment: I am not able to access to code right now but it seems to return some random memory location and when it is interpreted as string it shows random characters.

Comment: You should probably subm,it a bug report to the Mono project at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com